# String.Format format specifer as Pound Sterling

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, iis, string-formatting

I am using the following code to return my itemValue as currency.

`Return String.Format("{0:C}", itemValue)`

But this will return a string formatted as Dollar - is there any way to format this to return Pound Sterling?

Thanks, Guy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the CurrentCulture as @Steve suggests or just use it like this:

```
Return itemValue.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Before asking for the formatting change the CurrentCulture of your thread

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB")
```

Comment: Look also to the solution from @acfrancis. It is preferable if you need to change only in few places and keep the default for everywhere else

Comment: Nice one Steve, Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The string formatter takes currency and number formatting from the current culture of your machine. You can either:

1. Change the culture information on your computer
2. Set the culture explicit in the formatting:

   Return String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C}", itemValue)

Comment: As above - all of these answers are perfect. Cheers, Guy.

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler method.
As float, double, decimal etc. type has own formatting, throughout ToString() method.
For example:

```
double itemValue = 102.35;
Console.WriteLine(itemValue.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB")));
```